# Import C++ Dll in c#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllimport

There is a library written in C++, you must import it into the project to C# 
encountered such a problem 
I can not translate the code to C# function

```
short L862_GetResponse ( short hPort, short *Len, char * pData, long Timeout );
```

short *Len, char * pData
It is impossible to translate into C # these variables

Comment: I can not understand how to present this part: short *Len, char * pData

Comment: Usually, it is written C++ (without spaces).

Comment: Are you trying to link to a C++ library, or rewrite a C++ function in C#?

Comment: Assign through Dllimport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
short L862_GetResponse(short hPort, short *Len, char *pData, long Timeout);
```

Strictly speaking we need more information than this. For instance, `short*` could be an array, or the address of a scalar. And what is the protocol behind `pData`. Does the caller allocate a buffer whose length is passed via `Len`? Is the parameter semantics in, out or in/out? Only you can know by reading the documentation.

I'll take a couple of guesses. I'll suppose that `*Len` has the length of the buffer on entry, and the function modifies `*Len` to contain the number of characters written to the buffer.

The p/invoke would look like this:

```
[DllImport(dllname, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern short L862_GetResponse(
    short hPort, 
    ref short Len, 
    [In, Out]
    byte[] Data, 
    int Timeout
);
```

You would then call the function like this:

```
short Len = 256; // or some other size
byte[] Data = new byte[Len];
short retval = L862_GetResponse(hPort, ref Len, Data, Timeout);
if (retval != 0) // assume that 0 means success
    ... handle error
string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byte, 0, Len);
```

I've assumed that `Data` contains a byte array encoded as UTF-8. And that `Len` does not include a null-terminator.

I've made stacks of assumptions here, because the information in the question is incomplete. Please expect my assumptions to be wrong. Please check the documentation for the function.